# Validation issue With Date Program

Tags: java, validation, arguments

I have to validate the date,For example If I enter 31/2/2013,It should give an error as February doesn't contains 31 days,but I am stuck at how to achieve that,I tried to use the switch statement but still in vain.Help would be much appreciated.

```
public class Date
{
private int PDay;
private int PMonth;
private int PYear;

public Date(int day,int month,int year)
{
    setDay(day);
    setMonth(month);
    setYear(year);
}

public Date(int month,int year)
{
    this(1,month,year);
}

public Date(int year)
{
    this(1,1,year);
}

public void setDay(int day)
{
    PDay=day;
}

public int getDay()
{
    return PDay;
}

public void setMonth(int month)
{
    if(month>=1 && month<=12)
        PMonth=month;
    else
        System.out.println("Month Invalid-Must be Between 1 & 12");
}

public int getMonth()
{
    return PMonth;
}

public void setYear(int year)
{
    if(year>=1950 && year<=2049)
        PYear=year;
    else
        System.out.println("Year Invalid-Must be Between 1950 & 2049");
}

public int getYear()
{
    return PYear;
}

public String toString()
{
    return PDay+"/"+PMonth+"/"+PYear;
}
}
```

P.S. Its not Homework :P/>

**Test Program is:**

```
public class DateTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Date newDate = new Date(7,14,2012);
    Date newDate1 = new Date(2152);
    System.out.println(newDate);
    System.out.println(newDate1);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using `java.lang.Date` that's imported by default? What's your expected output for the test program?

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor, set the day *after* the year and month:

```
public Date(int day, int month, int year) {
    setYear(year);
    setMonth(month);
    setDay(day);
}
```

And in the method `setDay()` add the validation logic:

```
public void setDay(int day) {
    if (pMonth == 1 && (day < 1 || day > 31)) { 
        // throw exception or handle error
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid number of days");
    } else if (pMonth == 2 && (day < 1 || day > 28)) {
        // same thing
    }

    // ... rest of validations

    PDay = day;

}
```

If you want to be even more strict, you can use the year to determine if February has 28 or 29 days.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Don't implement date handling on your own as long as there are existing frameworks fitting your needs.

But beware of the pitfalls of some of the existing frameworks: (end of EDIT)

Don't use `java.util.Date` for such checks. Nearly all of the methods of Date are buggy and have been declared as deprecated. Those setters and getters have been reimplemented in the `java.util.Calendar` classes. But since they are still buggy in some circumstances the best choice would be to use the new Date Time API of Java 8 if this is an option or to use the "third-party" Jodatime library for correct date handling.

If you just want to have some checks on input, then you may use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` that handles the parsing and the checks.

Comment: OP is trying to write their own `Date` class.

Comment: I've seen it now, but even that is still a bad idea due to the complexity of the task. (At least leap year handling is required)